# Toilet keeps leaking from the cistern pipe going into the back of the pan

Tags: toilet, pipe, cistern

I have a persistent problem of the pipe leaking at the back of the pan, the toilet has been replaced, the pipe has been replaced and the seal has been replaced 3 times, it still leaks, I’m at my wits end wi5 this. Can’t understand why it won’t stop leaking after almost everything has been replaced.

Thanks
Brian

Comment: A picture showing where the leaking is will help.  Sounds almost as guessing where the leak is,  adding food colouring can help.   Are you sure it is not condensation causing the wetness/leaking?

Comment: Or could water be dripping down from above?

Comment: When you've replaced all the parts and the leak persists, it's time to consider that the person doing the replacing might be doing something wrong, even if it was you.

Comment: It’s definitely from the pipe coming from the cistern into back of the pan, i have placed a cloth directly below it sitting on the big waste pipe and the cloth is always wet. The pipe coming from the cistern is bone dry, it’s at the seal entering the pan. How do i add a picture, i don’t see the option anywhere? Thanks